# Drupal 7 - токен текущей страницы в вебформе

Tags: drupal7

Мне необходимо при отправке формы сохранять url страницы, с которой была отправлена эта форма.
Не вижу подходящего токена для заполнения значения поля, которое будет хранить эту ссылку.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: AJAX-ом отправляйте форму и будет с текущей страницы брать url - https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax